# Parental Control, limits per groups of application

Tags: parental-control

I've been testing qustodio and it's almost good for what I need, except I cannot specify a pretty important restriction, in my opinion: only x hours per day game-time.
I've been looking at websites with posts like "best X parental control software" but I was not able to find one that explicitly mentioned supporting this, so am turning to you, hopefully someone knows about this from experience.

So what I'm looking for generically is:

- multiple kids
- multiple devices (some shared) - windows PC/laptops for now. (would really like to not have to setup each device separately for 1 kid)
- able to specify daily screen limit (regardless of device)
- able to define hours with no screen time (eg during nights)
- able to specify at least daily gaming limit (regardless of games/devices) (best if that works for different application groups, so "school", "entertainment" (other than games) and games specifically, etc)
- able to ground a kid (temporarily stop access to gaming/entertainment without needing to modify the daily limits, still allow school stuff)
- it should be able to figure out that a specific application is in a group, but at the same time a specific URL could be in the same group. So we have online school, online music/video and online (browser) gaming and apply the group rules as such.

If the only way to get this is running 2 different parental control software at the same time on the same PC, and that is a compatible setup, that will also be acceptable.

I'm not looking particularly for free software, paid licenses are fine.

Thank you,

LE: as I got no replies, I am going through various top X parental control pages and picking the next untried "best" from it. Will post in separate comments my findings. Will do this until I find one that matches my requirements.

Comment: Qustodio: no gaming limits or similar; no temporary locking from what I could find, no app/url grouping. Deal breaker: at the moment of this writing, on a windows 11 Laptop, in FireFox when you get blocked on a site, you can simply refresh the page and it works.

Comment: Net Nanny: did not go much into its features because serious deal breaker: installed on windows 10 laptop and after reboot USB devices stopped working (mouse, keyboard, headset). Side, minor issues: reporting is incorrect: showed 0 minutes of usage after about 5-10 mins of screen time (as per the child); also the child played some browser game that was not blocked and was not showing up in the report either; he watched 2 different youtube videos, only one of them was reported. And all this with 0 screentime as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Norton Family: no gaming limits or similar; Somehow, the child is able to go way over their screen limit (it was 10 hours worth with a 2 hour daily limit; they said they were listening to music); it has no activity report so you have no idea what they are using and for how long; One day they were able to login before their allowed time in the morning and use the laptop for a while (10-15 mins maybe)

Comment: McAfee Family Safe: it has support to limit an application but it's not working. It has no reporting feature so you cannot see what, when and for how long the kid is using; You cannot specify time intervals for no screen time. Same goes for the manual "pause" of device: they can still use the device for as long as they want, you just don't get any kind of reports. It only seems to show a very short list of applications and they are all "Unknown" (Including Firefox, Microsoft apps, etc). Overall, it's the worst so far. It just doesn't work, at any level.